# Where can one see how klaf is made?

Tags: safrus

One elementary grade yeshiva in my area has a "creative" activities director that tries to hunt for some "unusual" day trips for the kids. Sometimes, I assist him.

I'm curious if there are any places in or near the New York City area where kids and adults can see how klaf (parchment) is made. I'm not even sure how I would begin to hunt for such places, myself. The only local *sofer* I know buys his klaf from a store, so I don't think he would know.

Does someone have some suggestions?

Comment: https://www.pergamena.net/ 1.5 hours drive from NYC

Comment: "...So I don't think he would know." Why not ask him? You might be surprised.

Comment: Why don't you ask your sofer  which store he buys it from and then contact that store and find out who their klaf-makers are, and find out if they might allow a public viewing?

Comment: @DoubleAA The pergamena clip made me think of the Gemara in Kedushin 82b "אשרי מי שרואה את הוריו באומנות מעולה אוי לו למי שרואה את הוריו באומנות פגומה...אוי לו מי שאומנותו בורסקי - fortunate is he who sees his parents in an elevated trade; woe is he who sees his parents in a lowly trade and follows them into their trade. ... and woe is he whose trade is as a leathermaker".